# Make all HTML-tags ignore browser responsiveness when page reaches 820px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using tags in my HTML that use vw (view-width) and vh (view-height) as their css width- and heigh-values.

I want ALL TAGS to stay in place once the browser reaches a certain width (820px or less). I want to basically "freeze" the site as it is at that width.

I tried with a media query, setting the container of all tags to width 820px. It does kind of achieve what I want, however all tags that use vw are still shrinking as I make the website narrower.

Is there a way to stop this effect without having to change all my vw/ vh values?

Thank you very much!

Comment: the `vw` and `vh` units work like percentages

Comment: I know this. @zgood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any element sized with `vw` you'll need to set a `min-width` at the point where you want it to stop shrinking. For example:

```
.container {
   min-width: 820px
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This would mean I actually do have to manually set a container for each element implementing vw and vh? I was just hoping that there would be a command for the browser to stop resizing at a certain width.. :(

Comment: Yes, because `vw` and `vh` will always be relative to the viewport size. You can limit its influence with `min-width` and `max-width`.